# Microsoft Flow connection issue Trello with Microsoft To Do/Outlook tasks

Tags: outlook, trello, power-automate, trello-powerup

Could you help me - how to resolve?

I try to connect though Flow my Trello task creation to Microsoft To Do, but every time i receive issue, see below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBodyRead",
    "message": "A null value was found for the property named 'DateTime', which has the expected type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.DateTime[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.DateTime[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cc1d5dae-def6-4d3e-8f1b-b09ac6883bc5",
      "date": "2018-05-01T10:33:38"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the Outlook Task connector expects a Due Date.
I use this expression in the Due Date field to auto assign a Due Date 7 days a

`if(equals(triggerBody()?['due'], null),addDays(utcNow(),7),triggerBody()?['due'])`